# Do not allow users to delete their resources after a certain time limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

if a User has many articles and these articles belong to a user. Then with a regular scaffold you want to set a time limit until it can no longer be deleted anymore:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to articles_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
    format.js
  end
end
```

How would you permanently disable the delete functionality for the User's articles?

Comment: The question at the end of your description doesn't seem to match the one in your title. The behavior described in your title most likely belongs in the model, not the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should hide this logic in the model and you should make it available as a public method:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def destroyable?
    created_at < some_time.ago
  end
  #...
end
```

Then in your views you can do things like this:

```
<% if @model.destroyable? %>
  <!-- delete button/link/... goes here -->
<% end %>
```

You'll also want a `before_destroy` callback in the model that [returns `false`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution) to stop invalid destroys:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your "can destroy" method conveniently returns false at the
  # right time so we can use it here too.
  before_destroy :destroyable?
  #...
end
```

You could also add an explicit `@model.destroyable?` check to your `destroy` controller depending on how you want to handle errors.

Comment: Yes, all business logic (= HOW and WHAT to do) should reside in the model. Deciding who can delete a record is part of that business logic.

Comment: Why have this be a `public` method instead of a `private` one?

Comment: @Railslearner: so that you can call it from the view and, if desired, the controller. If it was private then only the model would be able to call it unless you wanted to force people to use `send`.

Comment: Oh OK. Last question, I don't know why but when I write `created_at > 1.minutes.ago` it allows the deletion of articles before 1 minute. If I write the other way its the opposite. Shouldn't my sign be the other way? Seems like a bug.

Comment: The `destroyable` above has it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to block article deletion for articles older than one hour:

```
@article.destroy unless @article.created_at < 1.hour.ago
```

Allowing a specific user role (e.g., "admin") to delete an article of any age is an exercise left to the reader. ;)